# Async functions with no await

Tags: javascript, async-await, nestjs

I am developing a Nestjs web app with Mongoose as the interfaceing module for the database.
In an endpoint I am running two database queries(async functions), but I do not await them. I may have a wrong understanding of how async and promises work, but my expectation is that, after the end of the query is done, the unresolved async function will continue to run.

Here is the example:

```
removeRole(id: string | Types.ObjectId) {
  this.realmModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { roles: new Types.ObjectId(id) } });
  return this.roleModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
}
```

My expectation for this function is to return the `this.roleModel.findByIdAndDelete(id)` promise and to resolve the `this.realmModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { roles: new Types.ObjectId(id) } })` whenever will it be resolved.

If I make the `removeRole` function `async`, the result is as expected, but I am not particularry interested when will `this.realmModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { roles: new Types.ObjectId(id) } })` resolve.

Actual result:
What is actually happening is the returned promise is resolved and `this.realmModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { roles: new Types.ObjectId(id) } })` is not.

I don't know if this is a nestjs specific issue or a native js behaviour.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. What is the "not expected" result?

Comment: I've included an "Actual result". Thanks!

Comment: You say "I am not particularry interested when will this.realmModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { roles: new Types.ObjectId(id) } }) resolve" but don't you want it to happen before you call delete?

Comment: No. There are 2 different collections. The deletion of the role from the role collection does not impact the removal from the roles array from the realm collection.

Comment: I didn't vote, @Andy95. The first thing I'd try is changing the code to be a proper `async` setup so that you await both operations.

Comment: That works without any problem. You can do something like this:

`this.realmModel.updateMany({}, { $pull: { roles: new Types.ObjectId(id) } }).then();`

And everything works without any problem. I was more currious about the WHY. And sorry, I assumed you did since I can't see who up/down votes quiestions.

Comment: @Andy95 If they're independent I'd use an `Promise.all` and return that instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all to aggregate them.  This will also afford you the ability to error check

Comment: You have 2 independent promises here A and B - you are returning B and presumably expecting that A should be complete when B completes, but that is not correct.  By making removeRole async and awaiting both A and B, removeRole() returns a promise which waits for both and returns B.

Answer (score 0):

I don't anything odd right off the bat. What I feel is either of the following two scenarios might be happening:

1. updateMany is encountering some error which can be checked for by catching it and logging it.
2. The Node process exits before the updateMany async operation has had a chance to complete. (Not aware about any Nest JS specifics)

Comment: This is what I am thinking too. The updateMany has no errors. I've tried to error handle them, and no problem surfaced.

I think that after the return, the GC comes and sweeps everything up before the updateMany has a chanse to resolve.